# Motivation for Java Logging Customs

Tags: java, design-patterns, logging, coding-style, slf4j

I've been reading up on logging in Java and it seems like SLF4J is the way to go.

What I don't understand is why the logging object is obtained/initialized the way it is.

Why does

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
```

need to be in every class?

1. Why not instead have just some static logger instance for all classes/class-instances? (What happens if I don't create new instances for every class?)
2. Why do I need to pass the class object of the class the logger is being used in to the factory? Won't the logger have all of these details during runtime anyway? (What happens if I pass some different class object?)

Comment: It's not about how it is obtained, but about how you obtain it.
Technically you could create a singleton class, which gets a logger instance and use that instance everywhere else.

Comment: "What happens if I don't create new instances for every class?" - You can simply try that out! "What happens if I pass some different class object?" - Again - just do it and you'll see. Spoiler: the logger will be configured according to the configuration given to the backing logging framework. So, if you give App.class and App is in my.sample.namespace , you can for example configure you logging to log everything in INFO level for "my.*" but in DEBUG for "my.sample.*" ...

Comment: Surely the parameter to `getLogger` is different in each class? You usually don't specify a parameter at all and will get a logger object named after the class in which this statement is defined. Then you can see in the logs which class is producing the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can actually create a singleton logger that can be used anywhere. But we usually create a logger for each class just to filter logs.
2. this is just for naming the logger instance you have created, actually you can pass any string you want and nothing will happen
   ex: 
   `Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("any name");`